# Reduzir o código js e o número de requisições

Tags: javascript

como posso comprimir esse código em apenas um, para reduzir o número de requisições e reduzir o código js?

```
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.combobox').combobox()
    }); //]]>


    //----------------> SCROLL FILTER
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function () {
        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#sub-btn').click(function () {
          $('#content-body').css('visibility', 'visible');
          $('#content-body').css('margin', '0');
          $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#content-body").offset().top}, 1000);
          return false;
        });
      });

    });


    //----------------> TOOLTIP
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip({
            placement: 'top',
            title: 'Eles só precisam do seu minuto!'
        });

        $(document).on('focus', '.input-tip', function(){
            $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('show');
        });

        $(document).on('blur', '.input-tip', function(){
            $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('hide');
        });

    });    

    //----------------> TAB MAP UI
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(document).on('click', '.panel-heading', function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');        
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');        
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down').addClass('fa fa-angle-up');
        }
    });


    //----------------> TAB MAP UI
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slideleft button').click(function () {
           $(this).toggleClass('aberto').next().toggleClass('aberto');
        });
    });

    //----------------> JQUERY EFFECT LIST
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $('.close-carbon-adv').on('click', function(){
            $('#carbonads-container').hide();
          });
    });


    //----------------> BUTTON RETURN TOP
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function () {
        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('.return-footer a').click(function () {
          $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
          }, 1200);
          return false;
        });
      });

    });
```

Comment: você fez alguma tentativa ? tem alguma coisa que tentou para mostrar, assim alguem ira te ajudar mais facil

Comment: Este código me parece "um" apenas, quando você fala diminuir as requisições da de cada `<script src="">`? Juntar vários `<script src="">` em um arquivo só? Reduzir requisições ajax?

Comment: O que queres dizer com `número de requisições`? como queres reduzir o código, minificar? ou fazer mais DRY?

Comment: Desenvolva melhor sua pergunta para ela ser reaberta.

Comment: Porém, simplifiquei o seu código, como pode ver em http://jsfiddle.net/fh50gy1w/ e em seguida, comprimi [ http://jsfiddle.net/v2mkw7kx/ ], utilizado a ferramento Closure Compiler [ http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/ ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi errado a pergunta, você quer fazer isso?

Versão completa:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.combobox').combobox()
    $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip({
        placement: 'top',
        title: 'Eles só precisam do seu minuto!'
    });
    $(document).on('focus', '.input-tip', function () {
        $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('show');
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.input-tip', function () {
        $('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('hide');
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#sub-btn').click(function () {
            $('#content-body').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#content-body').css('margin', '0');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#content-body").offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
    $('#slideleft button').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('aberto').next().toggleClass('aberto');
    });
    $('.close-carbon-adv').on('click', function () {
        $('#carbonads-container').hide();
    });
    $(function () {
        $('.return-footer a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1200);
            return false;
        });
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
        $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');
    } else {
        $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
        $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        $this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down').addClass('fa fa-angle-up');
    }
});
```

Versão min:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.combobox').combobox()
$('.tooltip-icon').tooltip({placement:'top',title:'Eles só precisam do seu minuto!'});$(document).on('focus','.input-tip',function(){$('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('show');});$(document).on('blur','.input-tip',function(){$('.tooltip-icon').tooltip('hide');});$(function(){$('#sub-btn').click(function(){$('#content-body').css('visibility','visible');$('#content-body').css('margin','0');$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:$("#content-body").offset().top},1000);return false;});});$('#slideleft button').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('aberto').next().toggleClass('aberto');});$('.close-carbon-adv').on('click',function(){$('#carbonads-container').hide();});$(function(){$('.return-footer a').click(function(){$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1200);return false;});});});$(document).on('click','.panel-heading',function(e){var $this=$(this);if(!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')){$this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();$this.addClass('panel-collapsed');$this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-up').addClass('fa fa-angle-down');}else{$this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();$this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');$this.find('i').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down').addClass('fa fa-angle-up');}});
```

Comment: Exatamente Rafael. Qual a diferença entre o usar o comando "document.ready" e "document.on" ?

Comment: @HitchLeonardo Como não é o intuito da pergunta e teria que responder via comentário (o que deixaria bem confuso) vou te indicar um lugar onde está bem explicadinho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load